# Eliminar Pop Ups XCode

Tags: swift, xcode

Olá,
Eu tenho uma app já feita e pediram-me para lhe fazer um update.... o problema é que me pediram para retirar os pop-ups da app e eu não encontro nada para remover...
Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: É possível informar que tipo de popup é esse? Tem algum exemplo? Alguma tela? Eu não estou conseguindo entender o que são estes popups.

Comment: Tipo um botão INFO e ao clicar nesse butão aparece informaçã sobre o respetivo sitio...e eu quero eliminar o butao

Comment: Bastante confusa a sua pergunta, vc pode colocar um print da tela?

Comment: Você tem que olhar no seu código a referência do botão e remover o código correspondente a ele, além de remover o botão em sí da sua view, caso ele tenha sido criado com o processo de arrastar o botão da biblioteca de objetos do Xcode.para sua tela.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, como o CCastro falou sua pergunta ficou confusa, mas se o projeto for para iPhone e esta aparecendo Pop up, é bem provável que tenha o código abaixo na controller da view que aparece o pop up.

```
func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

Caso tenha esse código e você delete ele a pop up não é eliminada, o que acontece é que a viu que aparecia como pop up, agora vai ser carregada normalmente, ou seja no padrão do iPhone.

Mas na resposta ao Paulo Rodrigues que você usou o botão INFO como exemplo, vc diz que quer eliminar o botão, nesse caso o que Jadson Medeiros disse esta correto.